# I wrote code using pandas with python. I want to convert the code into a new dataframe with the output seperated into two columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I went from one data frame to another and performed calcs on the column next to name for each unique person. Now I have a output of the names and calcs next to it and I want to break it into two columns and put it in a data frame and print. I'm thinking I should put the entire for loop into a dictionary then a data frame, but not to sure of how to do that. I am a beginner at this and would really appreciate peoples help. See code from the for loop piece below:

```
names = df['Participant Name, Number'].unique()


for name in names:

    unique_name_df = df[df['Participant Name, Number'] == name]
    badge_types = unique_name_df['Dosimeter Location'].unique()

    if 'Collar' in badge_types:
        collar = unique_name_df[unique_name_df['Dosimeter Location'] == 'Collar']['Total DDE'].astype(float).sum()

    if 'Chest' in badge_types:
        chest = unique_name_df[unique_name_df['Dosimeter Location'] == 'Chest']['Total DDE'].astype(float).sum()

    if len(badge_types) == 1:
        if 'Collar' in badge_types:
            value = collar
        elif 'Chest' in badge_types:
            value = chest

    print(name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you expect len(badge_types)==1 in all the cases, try:

```
pd.DataFrame( df.groupby(['Participant Name, Number']).Total_DDE.sum() )
```

Otherwise, to get the sum per Dosimeter Location, add it on the groupby as

```
pd.DataFrame( df.groupby(['Participant Name, Number', 'Dosimeter Location']).Total_DDE.sum() )
```

Comment: I am not trying to get sum. I am trying to take the results of name, value and add it to the original dataframe or create another dataframe

Comment: can you amend the question with an example of input and expected outcome? In the current code, the sum of 'Total DDE' per name is done in the loop